# Index and search non-alpha characters in Lucene Java

Tags: java, lucene

The used version of Lucene (Java) is 4.2.1 and the used analyzer for indexing and searching is org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer.
The code below is in Scala but I think it is easy to read for anyone with C-like language experience.

Here is the problem:
I need to index and search text with non-alpha characters as well.
For example I have entities with names: "name 1", "name 2", "name 3", ... and I'd like to be able to search "name 2" or just "2" or even "me 2".

So far I have

the field:

```
val textField = new TextField("text", theFullText, Field.Store.NO)
```

and the query:

```
val parser = new QueryParser(version, "text", analyzer)

// case-sensitive search
parser.setLowercaseExpandedTerms(false)   // removed when MyAnalyzer is used

// To be able to search for text in the middle. Makes searches slower when the index is big!
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)

val textWithWildcard = s"*${QueryParserBase.escape(text)}*"

val textQuery = parser.parse(textWithWildcard)
booleanQuery.add(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
val topDocs: TopDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, 9999)
val hits: Array[ScoreDoc] = topDocs.scoreDocs
hits.map(_.doc) // return an Array of ScoreDocs' ids
```

A simple unit test:

```
"be able to search numbers" {
  for (idx <- 1 to 10) {
    val entity = new Entity
    entity.id = idx
    entity.name = s"name ${idx}"

    indexingService.index(entity)
  }


  val ids: Seq[Int] = indexingService.search[Entity]("name 3")
  ids.length must_==(1)
}
```

i.e. create 10 entities and then search the third one. The problem is that the result is 0.

Ideas what to change in my configuration to make it work ?

**Update**:
I've created my own analyzer to be able to support case-insensitive search:

```
class MyAnalyzer(ver: Version) extends Analyzer {

   protected def createComponents(fieldName: String, reader: Reader): Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents = {
      val tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(ver, reader)
      val lowerCaseFilter = new LowerCaseFilter(ver, tokenizer)
      val tsc = new Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, lowerCaseFilter)
      tsc
   }
 }
```

And now the result is **10**! 
Again this is not desired because the test searches for "name 3" but all entities are returned, i.e. it seems the numbers are cut both at index and search time.

Comment: Can you dump 'booleanQuery' to System.out?

Comment: Here it is: +(text:*name text:3*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND)
```

I have tried it earlier and it didn't work for some reason. I guess some other setting was problematic.

Answer (score 0):

To search for a group of words together in a field, surround the words with double-quotes.

I believe you can skip the wildcards (there is nothing between name and 3).

```
val textWithWildcard = s"\"${QueryParserBase.escape(text)}\""
```

Edit: Giving you 10 results is the correct behavior since the returned docs have different scores. 
You need to be able to distinguish between an exact match query and partial one when you search by Entity.

Comment: Surrounding with double-quotes doesn't change the results of 10. I think I need the wildcards because I want to be able to use search term line "me" where "me" is contained in "name". I don't follow you in the explanation why the result is 10. Why searching for "name 3" will return the document with "name 4" ? This is what I try to accomplish - search for "name 4" should return one result, search for "name 1" should return 2 results ("name 1" and "name 10").

Comment: You get ten results because you get a partial hit on "name" (due to default "OR" clause and the WhiteSpaceAnalyzer), but you have already figured that one yourself.